# Is there an opposite of a dirac delta function, a function that is infinitely wide and infinitesimally high?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, dirac-delta

Is there an opposite of a dirac delta function, a function that is infinitely wide and infinitesimally high?

The dirac delta function is defined as:
$$
\delta(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x \neq 0\\
\infty, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, dx = 1
\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x - a) \, dx = f(a)
$$

Is there a function:
$$
\epsilon(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon
$$
where
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon(x) \, dx = 1
$$

The dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is infinitely high but infinitesimally wide, this new function $\epsilon(x)$ is infinitesimally high but infinitely wide. Im guessing theres no such function/distribution given how limits work and it probably would not be useful if it did, but is there any credence to this idea?

Comment: Your definition $\delta(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x \neq 0\\
\infty, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$ is wrong and a common misconception.

Comment: @StevenClark what is the correct definition?

Comment: "Uniform distribution on $\mathbb{R}$" does not exists in ordinary sense. It is possible to concoct an object that may be thought of as a such thing, but its behaviors and applicability are far more restrictive than those of the usual measures and generalized functions.

Comment: One way to define it is $$g(x)\to\delta(x)$$ if $$\forall\,f(x)\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\, f(x)\,dx \to f(0)$$ which is satisfied by distributional [limit representations](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/) such as $$\delta(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(\int\limits_{-f}^f e^{i 2 \pi x t} \, dt\right)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(2 f\, \text{sinc}(2 \pi f\, x)\right).$$

Comment: The short answer: the Dirac operator is not actually a function defined on $\Bbb R$. It can be thought of as an operator on other functions, or as a particular limit of actual functions. In this second sense at least, one could probably find an analogous limit, although the limit function itself would probably be the zero function and it's hard to see much use coming from the sequence.

Comment: You are asking the wrong people.  You should ask physicists, not mathematicians.  To steal from Lewis Carroll, we pay our functions better and they work harder for us.  I do remember a class where the professor talked about taking the derivative of the delta function and almost had a revolt on his hands.  At the end of the lecture everyone was happy with the idea.

Comment: As others have pointed out, technically dirac delta is not a function but rather a functional. There are various ways to define it, one simple way as
$$\delta[f] = \lim_{n \rightarrow{\infty}} \int_{\frac{-1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} 2n f(x) dx$$
So conceivably an analogue to "infinitesimally high but inifinitely wide" would be to define
$$\epsilon[f] = \lim_{n \rightarrow{\infty}} \int_{-n}^{n} \frac{1}{2n} f(x) dx$$
Though I don't know how useful such a functional would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, the delta function is not a function but a distribution.  I won't complain about your definition but point out it really is the limit of a tall peaky function *where you have to be integrating over another function and you take the limit outside the integral*.  I would suggest a better definition is $\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} k(\epsilon)$ with the integral of $\delta(x)$ over any interval including $0$ to be $1$ and $k(\epsilon)$ being some tall peaky function, probably always positive and not doing strange things as $\epsilon$ changes.

In that spirit the obvious answer is to define a set of functions $g(\epsilon,x)$ as
$$g(\epsilon,x)=\begin {cases} \epsilon /2 & |x| \le 1/\epsilon \\
0& \text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$
It has the property that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} g(\epsilon,x)=0$ and the integral of $g$ over the real line is constant at $1$.  If you take $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty }^\infty f(x)g(x,\epsilon) dx$$ (note I have taken the limit out of $g$ and put it in front of the integral) you get something you can call the average value of $f$ over the real line.  You can get the same thing from $$\lim_{L \to \infty} \frac 1{2L}\int_{-L}^L f(x) dx$$
which just plugs in the definition of the $g$ I suggested and uses $L=1/\epsilon$.  I suspect this is not as useful as picking out the value of a function at a point which is what the delta function lets you do.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could consider the family of functions

$$\epsilon(x;s)=\frac{1}{s^2}\exp\left(-\pi~\frac{x^2}{s^2}\right)$$

We remark the following properties:
$$\int_\Bbb R \epsilon(x;s)\mathrm dx=1 \\ \forall s\in\mathbb R_+$$
and
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\epsilon(x;s)=0 \\ \forall x\in\mathbb R$$

However unlike the limit definitions of the Dirac delta distribution, the pointwise limit of this family is a well-defined function - that is, the zero function.